# c++ Void function interaction problems

Tags: c++, function, codeblocks, void

I have a possibly simple question
Is it possible to have to that void1 and void2 interact with eachother? Here's what i mean :

```
void void1(){
   void2();
}
void void2(){
   void1();
}
```

I mainly asked this because i have a school project and i'm kind of in a rush. Thank you

Comment: You need to declare function types: `void void1(){...}` etc

Comment: `while(true);` is an interesting alternative approach to this.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot that. I just made a mistake in the example though.

Comment: Short answer : yes

Comment: @skypjack it's a *better* approach, since it won't lead to a stack overflow. But I suspect there's some code missing from this example that breaks out of the infinite loop.

Comment: @trey Can you show me how if you have spare time? Thanks

Comment: In this code `void void2` would need to be predeclared at the beginning, like `void void2();`. That way it can be called in `void1`, even though its definition comes only after that of `void1` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call one function from the other, you have to provide a *declaration* of the function before you try to use it.

```
void void2();

void void1(){
   void2();
}
void void2(){
   void1();
}
```

Comment: so calling one of them is a behavior of an infinite loop